# Silence Exceptions on closing ssl connection with mysql and spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, logging, testcontainers

I have (spring boot) integration tests that use a test container for a (mysql)database.  When the tests end (even if they are successful), I get an ssl exception (see below).  I've looked around, and it seems this is an error with the mysql driver.  I would like to silence these so that in the event anything fails, I can easily determine from the logs (while right now, the majority of my logs are from this misleading exception)  Does anyone know how to silence these logs (I don't want to not use ssl).  For your reference, the logs are printed below:

```
2019-12-15 12:50:52.588  INFO 16171 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-12-15 12:50:52.588  INFO 16171 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
Sun Dec 15 12:50:52 EST 2019 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...

EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:



** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

STACKTRACE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:254)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:645)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:624)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.quit(NativeProtocol.java:1319)
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.quit(NativeSession.java:182)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:1750)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:720)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.quietlyCloseConnection(PoolBase.java:135)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.lambda$closeConnection$1(HikariPool.java:441)
at        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **


Sun Dec 15 12:50:52 EST 2019 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...

EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:



** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
...
rest ommitted for brevity
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just need to add

`logging.level.<package_name>=ERROR`

to your spring configuration properties
I would first try with

`logging.level.javax.net.ssl=ERROR`

but if it doesn't work try with different packages. Problem that I see in the log is that it looks like it was done not via standard logging mechanism but to `stderr`. If that's the case and properties approach won't work - then you'll need to specify your own `PrintStream` for `stderr`. That can be done with

```java
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int i) throws IOException {
                //ignore
            }
        }));
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexey, you were right in that I could override standard error output (making sure to put in before class, after class seemed to be after output was already printed).  Thank you